# How to unit test window.location.reload in angular 12 unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-unit-test, angular12

In my angular project, I have a function

```
reloadPage(): void {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

So when ever I need to reload the page, I used to call this function.

Now I am trying to add the unit testing for this function but it is not working.

```
it("reloadPage: should be validated", () => {
    spyOn(window.location, 'reload').and.callFake(() => {
      //test
    });
    component.reloadPage();
});
```

It still reloads the page on unit testing

How can I achieve a unit test for this function? Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: just as an idea, not sure if it would work - may reassign the `reload` method with a spy? `window.location.reload = jasmine.spy()`. Don't forget to restore the reload method after the test run

Answer (score 3):

I found the following solution to work.

In your component, inject the window with an `InjectionToken`.

```
const MY_WINDOW_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Window>('Window');
```

The constructor of your component then takes:

```
constructor(@Inject(MY_WINDOW_TOKEN) private window: Window) { ... }
```

In your module provide:

```
{ provide: MY_WINDOW_TOKEN, useValue: window }
```

In your test (spec) instead inject another (mock) window, by providing the mock / spy implementation in the TestBed configuration:

```
{ 
  provide: MY_WINDOW_TOKEN, 
  useFactory: () => {
    return jasmine.createSpyObj('Window', [...]);
  }
}
```

It basically comes down to isolating your subject of test from it's dependencies.

(**Notice:** all code is written from memory, and may need some modifications to actually work / compile)

Comment: this was super helpful, thanks... i was running into karma-coverage issues because window.location.reload causes the tests to fail with something like "your tests did a page reload!"

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide mock `Window` object in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

First create a window token

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('Window');
```

Create a mock object

```
windowMock = {
location: {
reload: jasmine.createSpy('reload')
 }
}
```

And then in `providers`

```
{provide: WINDOW, useValue: windowMock}
```

Comment: Results in `Cannot find name 'WINDOW'. Did you mean 'Window'?`

Comment: You have to create a window token before.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice solution using an angular internal function with **Location**.

```
constructor(
    ...
    private location: Location
) {}
```

And use

```
this.location.historyGo(0);
```

To reload the page. In this way you will not have problems with the tests

Answer (score -1):

There's no easy way to test if `location.reload()` has been called or not. It's not worth the headache either (also you should not refresh the page, this is a hack, and it's valuable on very rare occasions, like if you are playing with environment stuff on runtime)...

So to be able to test any logic for `onEvent` function instead (which is needed), and to skip any error derived by refreshing the page (which we are going to hide), you might have a component like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class SomethingComponent {
  ...

  onEvent = () => {
    ... some logic to test
    this.reloadPage();
  }

  private reloadPage = () => location.reload();
}
```

then the test will looking like this:

```
describe('SomethingComponent', () => {
  let component: SomethingComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomethingComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SomethingComponent ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomethingComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should do something onEvent', () => {
    // hack to change a private attribute of your component
    // strongly suggest not to use this as a routine
    component[ 'reloadPage' ] = () => null;

    component.onEvent();

    ... some tests here ...

    // do not test expect(location.reload).toHasBeenCalled()
    // it won't work and it's not worth make this working
  });
});
```

This will avoid the error on the refresh page and you'll be able to actually check any logic in your `onEvent` function.